# Object and array with self referencing

Tags: javascript

I am very interested in understanding JavaScript behavior.

Object :

```
object = {object : window.object};
object = {object : window.object};

console.log(object === object); // true
console.log(object.object === object); // false
console.log(object.object === object.object); // true
console.log(object.object.object === object.object); // false
```

Array :

```
array = [window.array];
array = [window.array];

console.log(array === array); // true
console.log(array[0] === array); // false
console.log(array[0] === array[0]) // true
console.log(array[0][0] === array[0]) // false
```

Why

```
object.object.object === object.object
```

returns false ???

Comment: Why define the variable twice, overwriting it? **Edit**: ok ;) It does not work without them

Comment: because first time window.object is undefined

Comment: If you know the answer why did you post the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first assignment, you have the following:

```
object = { object: undefined }
```

The second assignment creates a **new** object, whose `object` property contains the previous value of `window.object`, and assigns this to `object`. So now you have:

```
object = { object: { object: undefined } }
```

So at this time, `object.object` is `{ object: undefined }`, which is not the same as `object`.

Similar things happen with the array example.

If you want to create a self-referential object, you need to do:

```
object = {};
object.object = object;
```

This doesn't create a new object in the second assignment, it modifies the original object. Then you could do:

```
console.log(object.object.object.object === object); // true
```

For an array, it would be:

```
array = [];
array[0] = array;
console.log(array[0][0][0][0][0] === array); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two assignments to `window.object`. The first one creates a new object and assigns it to `window.object`. That one has a property called "object" whose value is `undefined`, because at the time the object literal is evaluated `window.object` is `undefined`.

The second assignment instantiates a new object. That one *also* has a property called "object", whose value is the object created in the first assignment.

Thus, `window.object` is not the same object as `window.object.object`.

The key is that in an assignment like this:

```
object = { object: window.object };
```

The value of the "object" property in the object literal is evaluated **before** the assignment takes place.

Comment: So there are two objects ?

Comment: Yes, there are two objects. Why wouldn't there be? Every distinct object literal expression creates a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Let explain it line by line

```
    object = {object : window.object};
    //here object.object is undefined and object new object so object !== object.object
    //lets obj1 = {object: undefined}

    object = {object : window.object};
    //here object is new instance of Object while object.object is equal to older object
   //basically object != object.object 
    // obj2 = {object: obj1}
    console.log(object === object); // true because same object obj2 == obj2
    console.log(object.object === object); // false because two different object  as obj1 != obj2
    console.log(object.object === object.object); // true because same object obj1 == obj1
    console.log(object.object.object === object.object); // false because undefined != obj1
```